# Regex to get words

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

Hello guys, I need to parse my textarea to get all words **(followed by spaces)** that has a `$` as a prefix.

For example, I have the follwing text:

```
my name is $Ahmad and I wish $peace to all the $world
```

Now I need to extraxt `$Ahmad` and `$peace`, but not `$world` (because it has no spaces behind).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) If you're not going to show any effort, why should I? Also, do you mean Java or JavaScript? The two are not the same.

Comment: I did alot of attempts and its javascripts 
here is my attempts 
\$[a-z0-9&-_]+[ ]  but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matches = str.match(/\B\$[^ ]+(?= )/g);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fpjZX/

P.S. assuming you meant JavaScript...